# Notepad++ Remove all except the text in the middle column

Tags: notepad++

I have a group of Indian surnames which have a number to the left and to the right. I need to strip away everything except the name.

I start with ...

```
 12  Rai     8,570
 13  Nath    7,700
 14  Goel    7,230
```

And would like to end with ...

```
Rai
Nath
Goel
```

I have a few of these lists to do and they all come in slightly different formats. I'm trying to learn what the Regex commands do, so I'd appreciate any quick description of what makes this work (I'm reading up on it too).

Comment: ([0-9])+( )+([A-Z])([a-z])+( )+([0-9]),([0-9])+ 
will mark them all 
You could, e.g. replace all occurrencies of ([0-9])+( )+ and ( )+([0-9]),([0-9])+ by empty strings - this will only leave the names there.

Comment: Please use Stack Overflow's [Search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) to avoid duplicate questions. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A good starting point for learning is a online RegEx tester like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/jA9rH9/1).

Answer (score 1):

you can replace [0-9 ,] with nothing

Comment: Semi works. It gets rid of some of it. Is there a simple command to remove everything except a-z and line-breaks?

Comment: Because it's case sensitive - do you really mean `[a-z]` in the comment above ?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have it in a text file line by line you'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)([A-Z][a-z]+)(.+)`
- Replace with: `\2`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\S+\s+(\S+).+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

`\s` stands for any kind of spaces.
`\S` is the opposite, everything that is not a space.

The second column is store in group 1, so when te replacement is done, only the second column left.